# C# WPF: Как правильно вызывать программное нажатие горячей клавиши?

Tags: c#, wpf

В WPF-приложении использую модуль `NHotkey` для обработки горячих клавиш.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("Test", Key.G, ModifierKeys.Alt, Test);
        }

        async private static void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            KeyboardManager.ModifiedKeyStroke(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control);
        }

    }
}
```

Благодаря 2 строке в конструкторе `MainWindow()`, при нажатии сочетания <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> вызывается метод `Test()`, который программно нажимает сочетание клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> для выделения текста в любом поле ввода.

---

**Проблема:**

Если убрать из кода строку `await Task.Delay(300);`, то текст в поле ввода не будет выделяться от программного нажатия <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> по причине того, что метод вызывается моментально, еще в тот момент, когда кнопка <kbd>ALT</kbd> (из сочетания <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) не была отпущена.

В итоге получается сочетание клавиш <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, которое не выделяет текст из-за лишней клавиши <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

**Временное решение:**

Чтобы решить проблему, я добавил в код метода `Test()` задержку в **300 мс**, чтобы было время на отпускание кнопки. В этом случае, если <kbd>ALT</kbd> была отпущена в течение 300 мс после нажатия, выделение текста от <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> срабатывает, но это не является нормальным решением проблемы.

---

Кроме этого мне приходило на ум как-то "отжимать" все нажатые клавиши перед вызовом метода, но правильно ли это?

В коде используется класс `KeyboardManager`, вот код от него: https://pastebin.com/f1xmZUW0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я понял, вам кажется надо подождать когда все кнопки на клаве будут отпущены пользователем прежде чем запускать автоматику.

```
private readonly Key[] keys = Enum.GetValues<Key>().Where(key => key != Key.None).ToArray();

private async Task WaitForKeysReleaseAsync()
{
    int threshold = 0;
    while (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.None || keys.Any(key => Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key)))
    {
        if (threshold++ == 100) // ~5 секунд
            throw new TimeoutException("Превышено время ожидания освобождения клавиатуры или произошло залипание клавиш");
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }
}
```

Ну и вызывать так

```
private async Task TestAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await WaitForKeysReleaseAsync();
    KeyboardManager.ModifiedKeyStroke(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control);
}
```

```
try
{
    await TestAsync();
    // здесь код, который надо выполнить, если всё прошло хорошо
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    // ... ex.Message, комбинация клавиш не была выполнена
}
```

Если клава через 5 секунд не освободилась, значит явно что-то пошло не так. К сожалению, в моей практике такие случаи были, приходилось даже перезагружать комп, потому что клаве было реально плохо, но это на самом деле редкость. В общем такой вариант исключать нельзя, потому что приложение просто может не дождаться освобождения клавы и зависнуть насовсем.

Comment: ого, я думал как-то сложнее решение будет, спасибо!

Comment: @denisnumb я просто переписал кусок из своего проекта в сторону упрощения :) уже давно разгрыз этот орех. И с горячими клавишами тоже сам научился работать без сторонних модулей.

Comment: не могу понять, как исправить ошибку "Неуниверсальный метод Enum.GetValues(Type) нельзя использовать с аргументами типа" в `Enum.GetValues<Key>()`

Comment: @denisnumb это какой у вас дотнет?

Comment: netcore 3.1, если об этом речь

Comment: @denisnumb Метод `Enum.GetValues<Key>()` доступен начиная с .NET 5, а для более старых фреймворков `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)).Cast<Key>()` надо писать.